# How to view Apple Card account information on a desktop computer?

Tags: web-browser, wallet

My phone died. I need to see my purchase history, receipts, and billing information for my Apple Card.

Can I find this information online? Or can I only find it in the Wallet app?

BTW the Wallet app appears not to be compatible with my iPad Pro 2nd generation.

Answer (score 2):

There is some info in System Preferences/Wallet & Apple Pay if you add the card there.  The main desktop interface is https://card.apple.com/  Neither of them shows the Mastercard account number or the most recent transactions.  You can see your statement history.  I hope Apple eventually ports the full Wallet app to Mac and makes a feature complete card web site.